# TensorFlow validation and training accuracy identical though validation and training set differ

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have tried to get a convolutional NN to output validation accuracy, using the test dataset as validation data (though I do realise that I would usually use a separate validation set). Now, accuracy on the training data, `acc`, and on the validation data, `val_acc`, are identical, though the two datasets differ.

Here's the code (tweaked from https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/courses/udacity_intro_to_tensorflow_for_deep_learning/l04c01_image_classification_with_cnns.ipynb)

```
!pip install -U tensorflow_datasets
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function

# Import TensorFlow and TensorFlow Datasets
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)

import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import tqdm
import tqdm.auto
tqdm.tqdm = tqdm.auto.tqdm
tf.enable_eager_execution()  

dataset, metadata = tfds.load('fashion_mnist', as_supervised=True, with_info=True)
train_dataset, test_dataset = dataset['train'], dataset['test']
num_train_examples = metadata.splits['train'].num_examples
num_test_examples = metadata.splits['test'].num_examples
def normalize(images, labels):
    images = tf.cast(images, tf.float32)
    images /= 255
    return images, labels
train_dataset =  train_dataset.map(normalize)
test_dataset  =  test_dataset.map(normalize)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu,
    input_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=2),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10,  activation=tf.nn.softmax)
    ])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
    loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy'])

BATCH_SIZE = 32
train_dataset = train_dataset.repeat().shuffle(num_train_examples).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
test_dataset = test_dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=3, 
          validation_data=test_dataset, validation_steps = math.ceil(num_test_examples/BATCH_SIZE),
          verbose = 2,
          steps_per_epoch=math.ceil(num_train_examples/BATCH_SIZE))
test_loss, test_accuracy = model.evaluate(test_dataset, steps=math.ceil(num_test_examples/32))
print('Accuracy on test dataset:', test_accuracy)
```

The output is

```
Epoch 1/3
313/313 [==============================] - 4s 12ms/step - loss: 0.3322 - acc: 0.8766
 - 49s - loss: 0.4049 - acc: 0.8516 - val_loss: 0.3322 - val_acc: 0.8766
 Epoch 2/3
313/313 [==============================] - 4s 12ms/step - loss: 0.3150 - acc: 0.8890
 - 33s - loss: 0.2631 - acc: 0.9044 - val_loss: 0.3150 - val_acc: 0.8890
Epoch 3/3
313/313 [==============================] - 4s 12ms/step - loss: 0.2484 - acc: 0.9087
 - 32s - loss: 0.2159 - acc: 0.9207 - val_loss: 0.2484 - val_acc: 0.9087
313/313 [==============================] - 4s 12ms/step - loss: 0.2484 - acc: 0.9087

Accuracy on test dataset: 0.9087
```

And as you can see, `acc` and `val_acc` are identical. I would love to know why.

In case it matters, `tf.__version__` is 1.13.1.

Comment: Is everything ok with the data? Tested on cifar10, can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: The data is coming from `tensorflow_datasets` so I assumed it would be ok (in that at least test and training data would be different). The `test_dataset` is of type `tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.DatasetV1Adapter` - is there an easy way to investigate it in this shape?

Comment: Try running a session and load train and test batch with the pipeline you're using.

Comment: @Sharky I get the same problem with cifar10, and also when I split the data from my original post differently.